# How to make Route setting after admin to be login in Meteor

Tags: meteor, admin, router

I created a collection for adminuser's enter the system.I mean I dont want to use account packet for admin side but I dont know How to make Route setting after admin to be login.I made something but it doesnt work correct,

> login.html

```
Template.login.events({
   'click #entre': function (e, template) {

        var Username = template.$('#username').val();
        var Password = template.$('#password').val();
        var getinfo= admin.findOne({});
        if (Username == " " || Password == "") {
            swal("Error", "All fields must be Completed.", "error");
        } else if (getinfo.username== Username && getinfo.password== Password) {
            swal("Success", "Welcome admin.", "success");

            Session.set("hi", true);
        } else {
            swal("error", "Login Informations wrong.", "error");
        }

    }
});
```

> router.js

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
    if (!Session.get("hi")) {
        this.render('login');
    } else {
        this.render('dashboard');

    }
});

Router.route('userList', function () {
    this.render('userList');
});

Router.route('addnewuser', function () {
    this.render('addnewuser');
});
```

Note:I want to make that when admin to be login,it can reach to all pages userlist,addnewuser etc.

Comment: I fixed some errors in the code. variables in JavaScript are case-sensitive. I will try an elaborate an answer for you.

Comment: oh thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it properly you want to give admin rights to certain routes of yours. There are several ways to achieve this using `iron:router`, either by building a Controller or using Filters. I would create an Iron Router Controller to tackle that and attach it to any route that needs that kind of checks. Both Controllers and Filters are actually reusable bits of code which is what we are looking for.

Make sure you add `alanning:roles` to your packages list (if you haven't already) and add some admin roles to at least one of your `Meteor.users()` like it's shown [here](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles#user-content-usage)

Building the actual Controllers is easy.

> lib/router.js

```
AdminController = RouteController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function () {
    var loggedInUser = Meteor.userId();

    if (!!loggedInUser) {
      if (!Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, 'admin')) {
        // Basic redirect to the homepage
        Router.go('homepage');
        this.stop();
      }
    } else {
      // Log them in when they are not
      Router.go('login');
      this.stop();
    }
    this.next();
  }
});

Router.route('/admin', {
  name: 'admin',
  controller: AdminController,
  waitOn: function () {
    // return subscriptions here
  }
});
```

Continue to add that to any other routes you like.

Comment: Thank you but it isn't my question's answer i think i  couldn't  tell correctly,i created collection myself it name is admin.there isnt  any meteor packet,collection have two documents tehir name are password and username,how can i control  them without meteor.userid (); is there any way to do?

Comment: Well, that's not really how one would test if an user is admin or not. Who is `admin` for you in this line: `admin.findOne({})`? Also testing `getinfo.password== Password` is wrong for so many reasons. Passwords are encrypted Strings, you can't just check them against an input.

Comment: there is one record in this Collection,and it is admin's information,cant give a role like admin it?

Comment: Your admins are also users (but users with special roles) so they should be in `Meteor.users()`. Follow the example on the `alanning:roles` README page